# Mantener una variable en session

Tags: angularjs

Tengo en mi controlador:

**app.controller**

```
//ESTO ME DEVUELVE UN LISTADO DE VARIABLES POR EJM
// [ {name:variable1, valor:2}, {name:variable2, valor:5} ]
$scope.variables = TestService.loadVariable()
```

Esto lo muestro en la vista y todo correcto, pero yo en la vista puedo querer cambiar por ejemplo el nombre de la primera variable a "`variablemodificada1`", si doy f5 vuelve a leer "`TestService.loadVariable()`", si ya se llamo una vez no quiero que se llame más

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mas tu pregunta, no entiendo bien que es lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: y porque no validas antes si tu variable esta llena??

Comment: porque cada vez que se recargar el controlador hay un $scope.variables = {}

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que dichas variables se guarden después de refrescar la página deberías registrarlas en los contextos globales del navegador (*local storage y session storage*). La principal diferencia entre ellos es que local storage se mantendrá activo siempre que tu navegador este abierto y local storage se mantendrá incluso tras cerrarlo).

Para acceder a ellos y guardar una variable en AngularJS sería algo similar a:

```
$window.sessionStorage["variable1"] = valor1;
```

Comment: y en la vista para pintarlo es {{variable1}}? porque no me esta funcionando

Comment: @sirdaiz Todo dependerá de como se llame la variable en la que recuperes el valor. Podrías hacer lo siguiente: `variable1= $window.sessionStorage.getItem('variable1')`

Comment: si pero yo me referia en el html, yo pongo {{variable1}} y no sale nada